# Need to move COMPLETED records from one table to other Table in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, archiving

I have million records in table and accumulating each second, so whenever the record marked status as COMPLETE I want to move that records to backup table.
This job I will be running periodically. Also I don't want to interrupt other operations in the DB by this move operation.

I have tried the below query.

---

```
insert into Table_Bakup  
select * from Table where batch_status ='COMPLETED' 
and ID not in (select ID from Table_Bakup )

delete from Table 
where ID in  (select ID from Table_Bakup )
```

---

But with the above query performance will be impacted. Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this?

Comment: I understand that you can create an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger to do that. As soon as row is updated, insert data into backup table, and then delete from main table.

Comment: What benefits do you hope to accrue from this exercise? What performance problems with your base table do you have?

Answer (score 0):

"Periodically" you mentioned sounds like a database job which is scheduled to run ... I don't know how often. Once a day? Every 2 hours? You decide.

Procedure might look like this:

```
update table set cb_to_be_moved = 1 where status = 'COMPLETED';

insert into table_bakup (col1, col2, ...)
  select col1, col2, ...
  from table
  where cb_to_be_moved = 1;

delete from table where cb_to_be_moved = 1;
```

Why `cb_to_be_moved`? As there are millions of rows affected, between your `insert` and `delete` statements there might be some other rows which are set to be "completed" (and those transactions committed). If you use IDs, yes - that works, but - you have to compare millions of rows in `table` with billions of rows in `table_bakup` so this (`cb_to_be_moved`) approach *might* be faster.

Database trigger? Yes, but - imagine what happens when it fires for millions of rows ... database might *choke*. Or maybe not; try to test it.

Comment: So your suggesting to add one more column with "cb_to_be_moved" ?

Comment: Yes; forgot to explicitly say it, sorry.